# Enter all subfolders - Recursive

Tags: c++, c, recursion

How can I write a program that enters all of a folder' subfolders?
I wrote some code, but it does not enter the subfolders.

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char* dirPath = argv[1];
struct stat statbuf;
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
size_t arglen = strlen(argv[1]);

if ((dir = opendir (dirPath)) != NULL) {
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
        printf(ent->d_name, "%s\n");
    }
    closedir (dir);
} else {
    perror ("Problem");
   }
}
```

I tried using the stat() function recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.lemoda.net/c/recursive-directory/

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
/* "readdir" etc. are defined here. */
#include <dirent.h>
/* limits.h defines "PATH_MAX". */
#include <limits.h>

/* List the files in "dir_name". */

static void
list_dir (const char * dir_name)
{
    DIR * d;

    /* Open the directory specified by "dir_name". */

    d = opendir (dir_name);

    /* Check it was opened. */
    if (! d) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Cannot open directory '%s': %s\n",
                 dir_name, strerror (errno));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (1) {
        struct dirent * entry;
        const char * d_name;

        /* "Readdir" gets subsequent entries from "d". */
        entry = readdir (d);
        if (! entry) {
            /* There are no more entries in this directory, so break
               out of the while loop. */
            break;
        }
        d_name = entry->d_name;
        /* Print the name of the file and directory. */
    printf ("%s/%s\n", dir_name, d_name);

#if 0
    /* If you don't want to print the directories, use the
       following line: */

        if (! (entry->d_type & DT_DIR)) {
        printf ("%s/%s\n", dir_name, d_name);
    }

#endif /* 0 */


        if (entry->d_type & DT_DIR) {

            /* Check that the directory is not "d" or d's parent. */

            if (strcmp (d_name, "..") != 0 &&
                strcmp (d_name, ".") != 0) {
                int path_length;
                char path[PATH_MAX];

                path_length = snprintf (path, PATH_MAX,
                                        "%s/%s", dir_name, d_name);
                printf ("%s\n", path);
                if (path_length >= PATH_MAX) {
                    fprintf (stderr, "Path length has got too long.\n");
                    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                /* Recursively call "list_dir" with the new path. */
                list_dir (path);
            }
    }
    }
    /* After going through all the entries, close the directory. */
    if (closedir (d)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Could not close '%s': %s\n",
                 dir_name, strerror (errno));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    list_dir ("/usr/share/games");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! works great, but maybe do you know why it's print in the directory path also ".." and "." ?

Comment: If you want to not print the implicit directories, you would need to modify         `/* Print the name of the file and directory. */
    printf ("%s/%s\n", dir_name, d_name);`
To check for (and not print) those two. It does this when it checks for performing the recursive call just below. It cannot recursively call the function on those two directories, because otherwise it would never terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Another example, using file tree walk (`ftw` or `nftw`)
These have the advantage of providing your own callback funtion with a `struct stat`, a filename and a type (FTW_D, etc.) Call fnmatch to eliminate unwanted entries.  Files that start with a "." are "hidden files". `ls` does not show them by default.  `ls -a` will list them.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ftw.h>

int callback(const char *fname,
             const struct stat *st,
             int type,
             struct FTW *ftw)
{
    // call fnmatch() here or use type to decide about printing
    // printf file name and type , ??? on stat error FTW_NS, default to "????"
    printf("%s\n", fname);
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     int fd_max=8;  // max file desriptors
   int retval=nftw( (argc==1)?"." :argv[1], callback, fd_max, FTW_ANYERR);
   return retval;
}
```